# Wordpress how to remove parent category and keep only child categories with post titles

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-wordpress-pages

```
    <?php       
     $categories = get_categories( 
              array('
              hide_empty' => TRUE
              ) 
            );
            foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <?php
                $args=array(
                    'cat' => $category->term_id,
                    'post_type' => 'ourservices',
                    //'posts_per_page'  => 10,
                    //'category_name' => 'our-services', // replace it with your category slug
                    'orderby' => 'name',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
    
                );
    
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                    ?>
                       
                  <h2 class><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                       <li class="list-group-item"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                    <?php }?>
                    </ul><br>
               <?php } 
                ?>
    
            <?php } 
            wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I tried with 'parent'=>0 but working with required result!
[image]

Comment: You would need to remove ONLY `our services`? Or all of the parent categories such as `private`, `commercial` etc.?

Comment: @Ruvee I only need to exclude "our services" and post titles under "our services".

Comment: Both `Our Services` and `g1`, `g2` etc.?

Comment: @Ruvee yes. "Our Services" is a parent category, but need to show only child category with post titles. Things in the red border I need to exclude you can see the screenshot given in this post.

Comment: Ok! Just wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `if statement` to check whether your parent category is the one you need to exclude.

So your code would be something like this:

```php
$categories = get_categories(
  array(
    'hide_empty' => TRUE
  )
);
foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <?php
  $args = array(
    'cat'       => $category->term_id,
    'post_type' => 'ourservices',
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',

  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    if ('Our Services' !== $category->name) {
  ?>

      <h2 class><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
          $the_query->the_post(); ?>
          <li class="list-group-item"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul><br>
  <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
<?php }
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thank you, it is working. Can we get the required result with some array argument like 'patent'=>0 or something like 'exclude-parents' => true

Comment: Ok Will accept the answer but first, we need to wait for some answers with some array arguments like 'patent'=>0 or something, 'exclude-parents' => true  or something else.

Comment: If you pass `parent => 0` argument to `get_categories`, only top-level (i.e parents) categories will be returned.